# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datetime, datepicker

I know this is a common error but I need some explaining on the best way to get out of this.

I have a datepicker used to store date of birth.

**DatePicker**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-100:-1",
            defaultDate: "-25y"
        });
    });
</script>
```

I pass it as a parameter to store in database as below:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtdob.Value;
```

works just fine.
Now on the edit page, i insert the DOB from database to a datepicker as below:

```
txtdob.Value = ((DateTime)rdr["DOB"]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

still works fine.I see the DOB as expected.
Now I just change something else(like name or city of the user) and click Update button with DOB passed as :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtdob.Value;
```

and i get an error

> Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime.

Comment: While saving into database convert `txtdob.Value` either using `Convert.ToDateTime()` or using `DateTime.ParseExact()` and instead of using `cmd.Parameters.Add()`(deprecated) use `cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue()` (recommended).

Comment: @Suprabhat cmd.Parameter.AddwithValue is not advisable, see this http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @JapzDivino: I'm well aware of this article, I have do read it before but I always follows what MSDN has for me. Have a look at this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, my bad on this one.I always use AddWithValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datepicker date format:  `dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",`
but you are storing on edit `((DateTime)rdr["DOB"]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");`

so, on update it's not working.

`yyyy-MM-dd` format working for  but `dd-MM-yyyy` not working,this is for some Culture Format issue.

so, you can Try using :[DateTime.Parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)
Or

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =
DateTime.ParseExact(txtdob.Value,
"Your_Date_Format(e.g dd-mm-yyyy)",
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I have read that you cannot manipulate the format of datetime stored in database.It is just how it is displayed in the table or in any of your controls.Keeping that in mind the above solution contradicts the theory.

Comment: @RelatedRhymes His solution holds good and your theory also holds good but here we are not manipultating the format of datetime when we are `storing` to the database . we are manipulating it when we are `retrieving` from the database.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the first few lines on 'How my code is not working' but this solution looks fair enough.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving error because if this `SqlDbType.DateTime`:

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtdob.Value;
```

You are passing a string to a DateTime datatype, that's why you received conversion error.

Avoid passing string to datetime datatype, even if you convert it, it is not valid, for example: **Name: Juan** , you cannot convert that into datetime datatype, you will received date formatting issues if you try to convert string into datetime.

If you want to correct that, you can add new string parameter, so that it will not conflicted to datetime parameter.

something like:

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SomeStringHere", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = txtdob.Value;
```

Then you can manipulate the flow of the program using `IF ELSE` condition, something like

```
    IF IsDate(txtdob.Value) = True Then
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtdob.Value;
    ELSE
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SomeStringHere", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = txtdob.Value;
```

Comment: I don't really want to get involved in using varchar coz then I would've change a lot of code in my project.I want to store it as a date variable only

Comment: @RelatedRhymes If you want to store as date only, you cannot pass a string to that date parameter, if you try to use conversion, you will receive also an error something like invalid date formatting , because any string is not acceptable to format into date aside to this one '20151007' , if that is the string it is valid, BUT if the string is something like name (Michael) or city (Chicago) , that is invalid conversion.

Comment: Kindly refer the answer by @ajmot.Looks somewhat what i was looking for.Thanks anyways